# In thread listView adapter is crashing xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {                 
            IList<ScanResult> scanwifinetworks = wifiManager.ScanResults;
            foreach (Android.Net.Wifi.ScanResult wifinetwork in scanwifinetworks)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (wifissid != (wifinetwork.Ssid))
                    {
                        wifissid = wifinetwork.Ssid;
                        lstSource.Add(new Person() { wifi_Rssi = wifinetwork.Level, wifi_ssid = wifissid });
                        Console.WriteLine(wifi_rssi);

                        var adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, lstSource);
                        lstData.Adapter = adapter;
                        Console.WriteLine(WiFiNetworks);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("EXscption");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }).Start();
```

If I try to do any thing in ListView, I am able to add but when I try to add in thread it is crashing (`lstData.Adapter = adapter;`).

Answer (score 1):

Modifying UI from off-thread is prohibited in Android. You need to post it to the UI thread and set adapter there.